# Django - Save Form Value in Different Views

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a small app in which a user can view an event, submit a form indicating the quantity of tickets they would like, view their basket and finally go to a checkout page.

My problem is that after I submit a form for event1, the value that is posted is lost when I try to view another event or refresh the basket. How can I prevent this from happening? I need to use Django to make use of a python module during the checkout process so I need to be able to retrieve the quantities submitted for any event in the final checkout view.

My views.py file:

```
def basket(request):
    context = {'Event 1 Tickets': event1_tickets, 'Event 2 Tickets': event2_tickets}
    return render(request, 'first_app/basket.html', context)

def event2(request):
    form = forms.TicketForm()
    form = forms.TicketForm(request.POST)
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            # form.save(commit=True)
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            return render(request,'first_app/basket.html',{'event2_tickets': form.cleaned_data})
        else:
            form = TicketForm()
    return render(request, 'first_app/event2.html', {'form': form})

def event1(request):
    form = forms.TicketForm()
    form = forms.TicketForm(request.POST)
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            # form.save(commit=True)
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            return render(request,'first_app/basket.html',{'event1_tickets': form.cleaned_data})
        else:
            form = TicketForm()
    return render(request, 'first_app/event1.html', {'form': form})
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(label="Ticket Quantity",min_value=1,max_value=9,required=True, widget=forms.NumberInput)
```

My event1/event2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="topnav">
      <a class="" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
      <a href="{% url 'basket' %}">Basket</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My static basket.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}"/>
    <!-- <script src="{% static "javascript/script.css" %}"/></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
      <a class="active" href="{% url 'basket' %}">Basket</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1>Tickets for Event 1 {{ event1_tickets.quantity }}</h1>
      <h1>Tickets for Event 2 {{ event2_tickets.quantity }}</h1>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="button" onclick = "window.location.href='{% url 'checkout' %}' ">Checkout</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

My urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('basket/', views.basket, name='basket'),
    path('event1/', views.event1, name='event1'),
    path('event2/', views.event2, name='event2'),
]
```

Comment: You might want to find a way to persist these events' data, rather than just passing them down the context repeatedly. You could set up a model ```Order``` to keep track of a user's order each time they start adding tickets to their basket. Then, it will be easier to render what is inside their basket later on, and change it.

Comment: This makes sense, but i'm not very familiar with Django so hoping you can clarify. If I have an `Order` model in models.py with two fields `event1Quantity = models.IntegerField()` and `event2Quantity = models.IntegerField()`, would my views.py be responsible for updating the model or would I need a 'ModelForm'? The documentation is quite confusing.

Comment: The views can use a form, or specifically a modelform if you want, to create or update an instance of a model. But, Is your goal to have many different events, and to allow a user to potentially purchase tickets to several different events in one order? In that case, I would have another model ```Event```. Then, your users ```Order``` can have a ManyToMany relationship with ```Event```. One order can have tickets for many events, and an event can belong to multiple users' orders. plan out the models and work outward, this is easiest.